# How to backup Android app related data like images, videos and files to Google drive

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an Note-Taking Android app using kotlin and I am a beginner. In my app I wanted to provide a feature to backup users data like notes, images and videos to their own Google drive. And also import the same.

I don't know how to do that. Can anyone suggest how to implement this feature.

Comment: You could take a look at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk, or you use the search engine of your choice to find tutorials that fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Google Drive API

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java

There used to be an Android SDK but now os deprecated so the Java wrapper or the REST API is recommended.

By using it you have to authenticate in behalf of the user, get permissions and then do the operations.